# ElectrumX returning 0 balance

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, wallet, electrum, full-node

I have a running full bitcoin node (txindex=1). I also setup electrumx and it has fully synced with current blockchain state.

Here's the log :

```
    INFO:LocalRPC:[2] RPC 127.0.0.1:44806, 0 total
    INFO:BlockProcessor:our height: 505,932 daemon: 648,872 UTXOs 826MB hist 236MB
    INFO:BlockProcessor:our height: 505,941 daemon: 648,872 UTXOs 831MB hist 245MB
    INFO:DB:flushed filesystem data in 0.13s
    INFO:History:flushed history in 3.9s for 1,249,360 addrs
    INFO:DB:flush #470 took 4.1s.  Height 505,941 txs: 295,160,913 (+337,771)
    INFO:DB:tx/sec since genesis: 1,976, since last flush: 226
    INFO:DB:sync time: 1d 17h 29m  ETA: 11d 10h 54m
    INFO:BlockProcessor:our height: 505,959 daemon: 648,872 UTXOs 838MB hist 18MB
    INFO:BlockProcessor:our height: 505,967 daemon: 648,872 UTXOs 842MB hist 26MB
```

But when i run electrumx_rpc query , its returning like this :

```
  No history found
  No UTXOs found
  Balance: 0 BTC
```

But I have balance in that address. How to fix this?

I installed electrumx using this [repo](https://github.com/bauerj/electrumx-installer).

Comment: It doesn't look like you are fully synced - ETA seems to be 11 days, with about 140k blocks to go

Comment: @RaghavSood Oh! I didn't notice that.